# Localhost has 403 error.

Tags: apache, cakephp

I am new to Apache but I found a tutorial online of how to configure Apache, PHP, and MySQL. Everything was fine until I tried to download CakePHP to my localhost. I did the following commands:

```
$ cd /Users/myusername/Sites/
$ curl -0 -L https://www.github.com/cakephp/archive/2.4.7.zip
$ unzip 2.4.7.zip
$ rm 2.4.7.zip
$ shopt -s dotglob nullglob
$ mv cakephp-2.4.7/* .
$ rmdir cakephp-2.4.7/
```

Then I decided I didn't want to use CakePHP and deleted the files from my localhost.

Now I am getting a 403 forbidden error stating "You don't have permission to access /~myusername/ on this server."

Can anymore help me get my localhost working again? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Apache are you using?  Are you running this on linux? If so, what version?  This sounds like an .htaccess issue or an issue with your virtualhost.

Comment: Apache 2.2.26 Unix which is the built in web server on OSX Maverick. I also just checked the error log and this is what it gave me...... [error] [client ::1] Options FollowSymLinks or SymLinksIfOwnerMatch is off which implies that RewriteRule directive is forbidden: /Users/myusername/Sites/

Comment: I am not exactly sure what that means or how to fix it.

Comment: Also I had upgraded from an older version of OSX which had a myusername.conf file already in place with the following text: <Directory "/Users/myusername/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the .htaccess file in /Users/myusername/Sites/